# Page object extending another page object

Tags: groovy, geb

I attempted to create a Page that extends another Page and got the following error message when I tried to run my project:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: navLinkPage1 for class: myPage

```
    import geb.Page

    class HomePage extends myPage {
        static url = "http://www.mywebsite.com"
        static at = { title == "Home"}
    }

    class MyPage extends Page {
        static content = { navLinkPage1 { $("#page1Link") }
    }
```

Every page is going to have the exact same page header block with the same links and whatnot. So how come I can't just create a page object of that and inherit it in individual pages after? Or did I simply do this incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you could include the block of code that actually uses the `navLinkPage1` link, I believe we could track down your exact issue with `navLinkPage1`, but it sounds like your block of code is going "`to MyPage`" instead of "`to HomePage`".

That said, consider the [Module Object pattern](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/all.html#modules) over the Page Object pattern for complex UIs (disclaimer: I just made that term up). So, instead of making every page inherit from `MyPage`, creating a (false?) relationship between the `Page`s, make, say, a "`NavigationModule`", a la:

```
class NavigationModule extends Module {
    static content = { 
        homeLink { $("a", title:"Home") }
        contactLink { $("a", title:"Contact Us") }
    }
}

class HomePage extends Page {
    static content = { navBar { module NavigationModule } }
}
```

and in your test, you'd say:

```
to HomePage
navBar.contactLink.click()
```

Personally, I've been treating modules like classes, and pretended their content is private, only giving myself access to operations rather than content. So, only accessing my `LoginModule` via the `logIn(user,pass)` method, rather than interacting directly with the `username` and `password` members... but... that may not work for you. A nav bar is particularly well suited to direct access. :-)

Comment: Thank you. I looked for my answer in the manual's Page Object section. I ended up finding it in the Modules section after reading your solution.